# Black screen on MacBook Pro login

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, power-management

I'm getting a completely black screen any time I log into my MacBook.
I enter login details and hit enter. It was getting about half way through progress bar displayed after this and then screen just goes completely black.

This all started when my laptop randomly went black while logged in the other day and browsing Facebook via Chrome.

I’ve tried all options (SMC and PRAM reset) from [this](http://osxdaily.com/2014/11/22/fix-macbook-pro-booting-black-screen/) article but none seem to work. I'm actually getting the black screen on boot up sometimes now too

I tried hitting the reset password using Apple ID on login screen also but now I'm just getting the progress bar in boot up and it also goes to black screen after half way.

Also tried holding the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key on boot to enter single user mode as per [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/122934/after-logging-into-osx-all-i-see-is-a-black-screen) quesion, it just quickly shows terminal options and then exits.

Can’t remember the exact model of the MacBook but I think it’s 2012 retina MacBook Pro.

Attached screenshot of trying to enter verbose mode with <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd>. It just quits this and goes to login screen after.

[image]

---

Managed to log in after hours of numerous attempts. Crashed to blank screen again after playing videos in Chrome.
Allowed battery to run out during day and started up again tonight, worked first time.....no crashes yet!

Here is report log:

```
Anonymous UUID:       7F3C3A92-2647-1A14-5366-FDCC0C1AF864

Mon Jan  1 00:01:23 2018

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 4 caller 0xffffff7fa54438d7): "GPU Panic: mux-regs 4 0 a0 99 3 8 severity 3 WS-ready 1 switch-state 0 IG FBs 1 EG FBs 0:0 power-state 3 3D busy HDA idle system-state 1 power-level 20:20 connect-change 0 : AGC GPU REGISTER RESTORE FAILED : rdar://7254528, VendorID invalid\n"@/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/AppleGraphicsControl/AppleGraphicsControl-3.20.13/src/AppleMuxControl/kext/GPUPanic.cpp:170
Backtrace (CPU 4), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff8202a53aa0 : 0xffffff8023c6c1c6 
0xffffff8202a53af0 : 0xffffff8023d95274 
0xffffff8202a53b30 : 0xffffff8023d87544 
0xffffff8202a53ba0 : 0xffffff8023c1e1e0 
0xffffff8202a53bc0 : 0xffffff8023c6bc3c 
0xffffff8202a53cf0 : 0xffffff8023c6b9fc 
0xffffff8202a53d50 : 0xffffff7fa54438d7 
0xffffff8202a53db0 : 0xffffff7fa54400d6 
0xffffff8202a53df0 : 0xffffff7fa544334b 
0xffffff8202a53e30 : 0xffffff802429eebc 
0xffffff8202a53ea0 : 0xffffff802429ede6 
0xffffff8202a53ed0 : 0xffffff8023ca5844 
0xffffff8202a53f40 : 0xffffff8023ca53a5 
0xffffff8202a53fa0 : 0xffffff8023c1d557 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl(3.20.13)[CAEF0436-9079-33B1-B4F4-30B831C565FC]@0xffffff7fa5435000->0xffffff7fa5447fff
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl(3.20.13)[21FE5549-B94B-3EF9-9BF1-76114C50CB52]@0xffffff7fa5406000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily(1.4)[95DA39BB-7C39-3742-A2E5-86C555E21D67]@0xffffff7fa4f88000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[AEA4C7F5-CCB0-338B-B471-CF28A9792522]@0xffffff7fa4494000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(519.20)[0E507098-E375-39B7-9AE2-AFF2C7A5D961]@0xffffff7fa4804000
            dependency: com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl(3.20.13)[55E796DB-EFBA-34DB-8148-E834A4383AD2]@0xffffff7fa486a000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task

Mac OS version:
17G65

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 17.7.0: Thu Jun 21 22:53:14 PDT 2018; root:xnu-4570.71.2~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 1AE5ACFD-3B6F-3D74-AD52-31F1430DBC6F
Kernel slide:     0x0000000023a00000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8023c00000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8023b00000
System model name: MacBookPro10,1 (Mac-C3EC7CD22292981F)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 2310204569872
last loaded kext at 1619333413141: com.apple.driver.AppleXsanScheme 3 (addr 0xffffff7fa7591000, size 32768)
last unloaded kext at 1681625019243: com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub  900.4.1 (addr 0xffffff7fa74ee000, size 12288)
loaded kexts:
com.apple.filesystems.afpfs 11.1
com.apple.nke.asp-tcp   8.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor  1.9.5d0
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.driver.AGPM   110.23.37
com.apple.driver.ApplePlatformEnabler   2.7.0d0
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    131
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   281.52
com.apple.AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics  3.20.13
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   281.52
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.5
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    6.0.7f10
com.apple.driver.pmtelemetry    1
com.apple.GeForce   10.3.2
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD4000Graphics   10.3.6
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.eficheck   1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 3.1.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC   1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   3.1
com.apple.driver.AGDCBacklightControl   3.20.13
com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl    3.20.13
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelFramebufferCapri 10.3.6
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    211
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking 4.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.5.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 254
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  254
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.kext  407.50.6
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 40
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0
com.apple.AppleSystemPolicy 1.0
com.apple.filesystems.apfs  748.51.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSDXC  1.7.6
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4360   1240.19.1a3
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  329.50.2
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 220.50.1
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   183
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   220.50.1
com.apple.security.SecureRemotePassword 1.0
com.apple.driver.usb.cdc.ncm    5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.cdc    5.0.0
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 281.52
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    526
com.apple.iokit.IOAVBFamily 680.2
com.apple.plugin.IOgPTPPlugin   680.15
com.apple.driver.AppleSSE   1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAGK100Hal    10.3.2
com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAResman  10.3.2
com.apple.AppleGPUWrangler  3.20.13
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 281.52
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 281.52
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   206.5
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.14d1
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.20.13
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2    378.26
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   211.15
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.20.13
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 6.0.0d8
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.1.0
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   519.20
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.18d1
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    519.20
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 6.0.7f10
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   6.0.7f10
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerTransport  6.0.7f10
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   6.0.7f10
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 262
com.apple.driver.usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.networking 5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice    1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHub    1.2
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext    1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    5.5.5
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    5.5.5
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 2.1.3
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  301.40.2
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    4.7.2
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 6.7.8
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.1.0
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   1200.12.2
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.driver.corecapture    1.0.4
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    288
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBEHCIPCI    1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBEHCI   1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCIPCI    1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCI   1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostPacketFilter   1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 900.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHostMergeProperties    1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 480.60.1
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleEffaceableStorage 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTDM    439.70.3
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageDriver  140.70.2
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   404.30.2
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   404.30.2
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.KernelRelayHost    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily 1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBCommon 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBusPowerController    1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSEPManager    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.IOSlaveProcessor   1
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  31
com.apple.iokit.IOTimeSyncFamily    680.15
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.4
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0

EOF
Model: MacBookPro10,1, BootROM MBP101.00F6.B00, 4 processors, Intel Core i7, 2.6 GHz, 16 GB, SMC 2.3f36
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 4000, Intel HD Graphics 4000, Built-In
Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M, NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M, PCIe
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D5434314753364D465238432D50422020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D5434314753364D465238432D50422020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0xEF), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.21.190.18.1a3)
Bluetooth: Version 6.0.7f10, 3 services, 18 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD SM256E, 251 GB
USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)
USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 23.4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it’s getting repaired for free under ECLC even though 5 and a half years old!, happy days!

Here’s the report:
Issue replicated, running diagnostics
MRI failed on battery 
Battery test failed 
VST failed

Device needs a new logic board and a top case with battery under ECLC

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that stands out to me in that log is the line

> "GPU Panic: mux-regs 4 0 a0 99 3 8 severity 3 WS-ready 1 switch-state 0 IG FBs 1 EG FBs 0:0 power-state 3 3D busy HDA idle system-state 1 power-level 20:20 connect-change 0 : AGC GPU REGISTER RESTORE FAILED : rdar://7254528, VendorID invalid\n"@/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/AppleGraphicsControl/AppleGraphicsControl-3.20.13/src/AppleMuxControl/kext/GPUPanic.cpp:170
>   Backtrace (CPU 4), Frame : Return Address

Everything else just looks very Apple ordinary.

I'm not a pro yet, but considering you were also using Google chrome, which uses "Hardware Acceleration", pushing your GPU, I am definitely thinking you may have a gpu that's starting to go bad or become defective.

Comment: I dropped into a compuB store who are an apple authorized service provider in Ireland seen as there is no apple store here.
Helpful guy told me it will most likely be covered by Apple under ECLC consumer law (Up to 6 years from purchase). Filled out forms and left it with them, will have more info in few days.

Comment: @ThomasBuckley keep me posted.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple more basic things that you can try. 
First, create a bootable usb of mac os on another computer using createinstallmedia commands in terminal.  You can find thos instructions [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372)

Then insert your bootable usb of mac OS and hold down the control key until you get to a boot screen. Select your usb key "install mac os high sierra" on the boot screen, and hit enter. See if it loads to the installation screen. If it does, try reinstalling to the same drive without re-partitioning or formatting your drive. As long as you dont format, none of your personal data will be lost. You will just be reinstalling the core OS. Once installed, boot back up and see if your screen is fixed. If not, then it most likely is a hardware problem and not a software problem. Could be a faulty graphics card or something. But try reinstalling mac os forst and let me know how that goes.

Comment: I managed to fluke my way to logging in..not sure how I used so many different ways. Computer just randomly shutdown again later in evening when watching video using Chrome....I think that's what triggered blank screen first time also.
I've attached the error report to orginal question, I wonder is Graphics card related as you stated?
Is there a way to disable the card and just use the integrated one?