# MacBook Pro with TouchBar (late 2016) has black display but works with external monitor

Tags: macbook-pro, display, hardware, screen, repair

I’ve a late 2016 MacBook Pro (4 Thunderbolt ports and Touch Bar), with Monterey 12.2 installed on it. The MacBook was perfectly working when the other day the screen suddenly went black while browsing on internet. In the last months I noticed that the brightness was loosing power, but now I can’t see anything, although the Mac is working (for example once turned on the caps lock works).

I tried all the tests about Safe Boot and NVRAM reset, but nothing. The issue is similar to the one in this question:

[Black screen on MacBook Pro login](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/336215/black-screen-on-macbook-pro-login)

At the support they told me it can be the GPU and they asked for 600 $ to repair it!

Did it happen to someone else who found a cheaper way to solve this? For example, I’ve seen some videos that show how to open the Mac and try to fix this issue:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SKejJwQ3MGU

Thank you very much in advance for your help! It’s really appreciated.

---

**Edit after @cmason comment**: if I connect the MacBook Pro to and external monitor (in my case a projector I use often in combination with Mac) I can see my Desktop AFTER logging in, and everything works as usual.

Comment: How about an external monitor? Does that work? if not, definitely the GPU or mainboard issue

Comment: No matter what, MAKE A BACKUP!

Comment: @cmason your idea worked! I connected the MacBook to my projector, I restarted it and put the password (on the black screen, hoping I was doing it correctly) AND I CAN SEE MY DESKTOP AGAIN THROUGH THE PROJECTION! Thank you so much for giving me this idea.

What should I do now? How can I fix the screen?

Comment: Likely your screen, perhaps the cable leading to the screen has gone bad. With Macbooks, it often requires replacing the entire lid, screen and all, and sometimes the main board.  Take it to an Apple repair shop for diagnosis and estimate and then decide if its worth saving

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, there is a **worldwide warranty for this type of problem**. It refers to the first MacBook Pro released in the same period as mine, since they can come with a flaw related to the screen.

You can find all the details here: https://support.apple.com/13-inch-macbook-pro-display-backlight-service?fbclid=IwAR1fWw-jfSqmA_3IUQDQZDYWN1pFYCycXlAnmCllco20qXvXH8TeCDOJZzA

Today I went to an authorized Apple center, told them about my problem and this warranty (along with the fact that with an external monitor everything was working) and **they will change the screen for free**.